# Artifactory is not caching the maven-metadata.xml file

Tags: maven, maven-3, artifactory, maven-metadata

Is there a way to make the artifactory to cache the maven-metadata.xml file?

Every time that I release a version of my artifact it takes a lot of time search new versions of artifacts.

Is it possible to chose on the Artifactory a "time cache" for that file?

Answer (score 0):

Artifactory 2 stores Maven metadata in the database (with the rest of the metadata on artifact) and generates XML on demand. It is cheap process and shouldn't take "a long time". Probably the lag is somewhere else.

Artifactory 3 caches Maven metadata as any other artifact and generally much faster. Like 10 times faster.